# Control Flow of Strapi Admin Panel

Tags: controller, node-modules, strapi

I am using the community edition of strapi, as by installing the **npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart** In this, i signup with admin account on localhost, but when we create Collection Types and add some data in that collection, like having Categories as Collection and we enter the name of the Category as Dinner or something else. I want to know the flow of the api where its stores in which folder it exists. I checked in the api folder there is only routes defined and nothing in the services and controllers.
I checked for the documentation, but nothing find in that.

Like in a Scenario, I want if the collection created or updated by admin panel, it will be printed in the console. Basically I want to override the controller of admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, The Operations done through admin Ui goes through

> \extensions\content-manager\controllers\collection-types.js

and UI will be present at

> \extensions\content-manager\admin\src\components\CustomTable\ActionCollapse\index.js

also strapi default code for RestAPI operations is stored at

> \node_modules\strapi\lib\core-api\Controller.js

(This file is responsible for the default actions unless u have over-written with your own in the .api folder)

Comment: I tried this before, but when i override the update function present in the controller it will override all the request. I want It will work for some request or routes because i want some more things in that. Like when user signup it will get a welcome message on their email etc. As you suggest me by adding function in api folder, i tried but not working. I want to override some function of admin panel end points.

Comment: You can put a if check based on the model. Each collection will have it's unique model name. It will be something like application :: categories.categories